# Problems building Google Drive API File Upload

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to build an android app that'll allow me to upload files to Google Drive upon requirement of the user. But, I can't find a single working example anywhere. There are half baked snippets scattered here and there. Some of them are able to connect through OAuth, others are able to create an empty file or folder, but nowhere I can find an app that saves the tokens, and uploads the files seamlessly. I am just clueless as to how to implement the functionality as no books or videos are available, google's own samples don't work for me. I'm struggling to make the code work. Please help someone. Thanks.

Comment: `I'm struggling to make the code work.` ... **which** code?

Comment: The code I've been writing trying to make it work somehow using the available snippets, but which is still not working. I can't post it. It' all a large mess.

Comment: And so we are supposed to **imagine** your code? Have a nice day.

Comment: No like I asked before you could point me to somewhere where the code given works, or atleast there is a good tutorial finishing which I'll be able to build it myself. I don't desire any code corrections. Just the resource links would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: Totally **off-topic**. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Comment: he can make this question useful if he puts some of the code that he tried.

Comment: ... and stops asking for tutorials.

Comment: Well I got some code below, I'll try it and see if I can make it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the class below to create a Google drive service.

First you need to have these dependencies on your pom file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev282-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use this class to create instance of the drive api client :

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author jalal-sordo
 */
public class GoogleDriveServiceFactory {

    private String applicationName;

    private JsonFactory jsonFactory;
    private HttpTransport googleDriveHttpTransport;
    private List<String> googleDriveApiScopes;
    private String googleDriveClientSecretFilePath;
    private FileDataStoreFactory credentialsStoreFolder;

    public GoogleDriveServiceFactory(ApplicationParameters params) {
        try {
            this.googleDriveClientSecretFilePath = params.getGoogleDriveClientSecretFilePath();
            //  = new FileInputStream(googleDriveClientSecretFilePath);
            applicationName = "someApplicationName";
            jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            googleDriveApiScopes = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
            googleDriveHttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            java.io.File googleDriveCredentialsStore = new java.io.File(params.getGoogleDriveCredentialsFolderPath());
            credentialsStoreFolder = new FileDataStoreFactory(googleDriveCredentialsStore);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException t) {
            System.err.println(t.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new FileReader(new java.io.File(googleDriveClientSecretFilePath));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
                = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, streamReader);
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
                = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        googleDriveHttpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, googleDriveApiScopes)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(credentialsStoreFolder)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

        return credential;
    }

    public Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                googleDriveHttpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(applicationName)
                .build();
    }
}
```

You will also need this class to provide parameters to the class above :

```
/**
 *
 * @author jalal-sordo
 */
public class ApplicationParameters {

    private String googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath;
    private String googleDriveClientSecretFilePath;

    public String getGoogleDriveCredentialsFolderPath() {
        return googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath;
    }

    public void setGoogleDriveCredentialsFolderPath(String googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath) {
        this.googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath = googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath;
    }

    public String getGoogleDriveClientSecretFilePath() {
        return googleDriveClientSecretFilePath;
    }

    public void setGoogleDriveClientSecretFilePath(String googleDriveClientSecretFilePath) {
        this.googleDriveClientSecretFilePath = googleDriveClientSecretFilePath;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplicationParameters{"
                + "\ngoogleDriveCredentialsFolderPath = " + googleDriveCredentialsFolderPath
                + "\ngoogleDriveClientSecretFilePath = " + googleDriveClientSecretFilePath
               + "\n}";
    }

}
```

And this is how you can create an instance of the GoogleDriveServiceFactory and perform a file upload :

```
ApplicationParameters params = new ApplicationParameters();
//this is where you specify where you want the credentials to be stored
//after a successful autherization is made from the browser (this code will 
//open the authorization consent page on your default browser).
params.setGoogleDriveCredentialsFolderPath("/path/to/credentials/folder");
//this is the path to your client_id that you downloaded from google cloud
//console credentials page.
params.setGoogleDriveClientSecretFilePath("/path/to/client_id.json");
GoogleDriveServiceFactory  driveFactory = new GoogleDriveServiceFactory (params);

File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveFactory.getDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```